# Replace Placeholder with Value from other table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let say I have a stored procedure that will insert record into table1

```
INSERT INTO tbl_table1 (Id, Parameter)
Select Id, Parameter
FROM tbl_table2
```

And example for table2 and table3 as below:

tbl_table2 - Not every field has Parameter

| Id | Field | Parameter |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Field1 | A = [As_Of_Date], B = [itemType] |
| 2 | Field2 | NULL |

tbl_table3 - Specify the value for the itemType

```
   | Id       |   itemType    |
   | -------- | ------------  |
   | 1        |  Type1        |
   | 2        |  Type2        |
```

I have to update the string (A = [As_Of_Date], B = [itemType]) with value taken from table3, and the As_Of_Date is the parameter by the stored procedure, @As_Of_Date.

for example the result will be like this

tbl_table1

```
   | Id       | Data                       |
   | -------- | ---------------------------|
   | 1        | A = 2021-01-01, B = Type1  |
   | 2        | NULL                       |
```

Any way to implement this?

Comment: I'm really confused about what you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry. I have updated my question, let me know if any part still unclear.

Comment: There is no straightforward way to implement such functionality in SQL. I think you should consider redesigning you schema.

Comment: @DDF . . . (1) This is a really bad data model.  (2) The question is still unclear.  Is "placeholder" supposed to correspond to something in another table?  If so, why isn't the same name used in both places?  (Fixing that would make a really bad data model only slightly less bad.)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your intent correctly, then you want to insert Id from table2 and Parameter from table3 which is a join in the SELECT statement:

```
INSERT INTO table1( Id, Parameter)
SELECT 
  tbl2.Id,
  tbl3.Parameter
FROM
  table2 AS tbl2
  -- link to result
  INNER JOIN table3 AS tbl3
    ON  tbl3.Id = tbl2.Id
;
```

Is this good enough?

Comment: I will have to replace the placeholder in  A =[placeholder1], B = [placeholder2] to data from table 3, the data in table 1 should be for first record, the Parameter column is, [A =Data1, B = Data2]

Comment: Have you tried the REPLACE() function? You might need to write a dynamic SQL query to properly replace the placeholders.

Comment: Terence I think you are right, probably need a dynamic SQL. But I'm not sure where to start, could you give me some insight of it? Probably an example?

Answer (score 0):

..cluttered recursion, just clean it up if all placeholders appear in table3

```
declare @table2 table(id int identity, Parameter varchar(max));
insert into @table2(Parameter)
values('A =[placeholder1], B = [placeholder2]'), (null), 
('A = [placeholder1]*[placeholder3]-[placeholder2]'),
('X=[placeholder4]*[placeholder1]/[placeholder2]'),
('Y=[placeholder2]*[placeholder4]+ [placeholder2]*[placeholder2]'),
('[placeholder6]'), ('[placeholder6]+[placeholder1]'),
('[placeholder]*[placeholder4]'),('[placeholderX]'),
('[placeholderX]+[placeholder2]-[placeholder3]+[placeholder4]*[placeholderY]');

declare @table3 table(id int, Data varchar(100));
insert into @table3(id, Data)
values(1, 'Data1'), (2, 'Data2'), (3, 'Data3'), (4, 'Data4');


--..clutter to handle placeholders which do not exist in @tbl3
with r
as
(
select 
    t2.id,
    case when exists(select * from @table3 as t3 where t2.Parameter like concat('%[[]placeholder', t3.id, ']%')) then 1 else 0 end as hasmatchedplaceholders,
    t2.Parameter,
    isnull(charindex('[placeholder', t2.Parameter, 1), 0) as placeholderpos,
    1 as lvl
from @table2 as t2
union all
select
    d.id, 
    case when 
    charindex('[placeholder', d.Parameter, charindex('[placeholder', d.Parameter, d.placeholderpos+1)+1) = 0
    and d.placeholderpos > 0 and d.hasmatchedplaceholders > 0 then 
        case when exists(select * from @table3 as t3 where d.Parameter like concat('%[[]placeholder', t3.id, ']%')) then 1 else 0 end 
    else d.hasmatchedplaceholders end as hasmatchedplaceholders,
    d.Parameter, 
    isnull(charindex('[placeholder', d.Parameter, d.placeholderpos+1), 0) as placeholderpos, d.lvl
from
(
    select
    r.id, r.hasmatchedplaceholders, r.placeholderpos,
    replace
    (
        r.Parameter, 
        substring(r.Parameter, r.placeholderpos, charindex(']' ,r.Parameter, r.placeholderpos) - r.placeholderpos+1),
        isnull
        (
            (
            select t3.Data
            from @table3 as t3
            where t3.id = try_cast(substring(r.Parameter, r.placeholderpos + len('[placeholder'), charindex(']' ,r.Parameter, r.placeholderpos) - r.placeholderpos-len('[placeholder')) as int)
            )
        , substring(r.Parameter, r.placeholderpos, charindex(']' ,r.Parameter, r.placeholderpos) - r.placeholderpos+1))--isnull()..end
    ) as Parameter,
     r.lvl+1 as lvl
    from r
    where exists(select * from @table3 as t3 where r.Parameter like concat('%[[]placeholder', t3.id, ']%'))
    and r.lvl <= 100 --100 distinct placeholders
) as d
)
select id, Parameter --*
from r
where placeholderpos = 0
or hasmatchedplaceholders = 0
order by id;
```